# City level rendering in D3

Tags: mapping, d3.js, projection

I'm trying to render a projection using data from Open Street Maps. I downloaded the Sweden transportation file from [here](http://vdstech.com/osm-data.aspx) and converted the buildings shapefile to topojson. This is an excerpt:

```
{"type":"Topology","transform":{"scale":[0.0013154551155115512,0.0013336730673067306],"translate":[11.0320167,55.3382768]},"objects":{"buildings":{"type":"GeometryCollection","geometries":[{"type":"Polygon","arcs":[[0,1,2]]},{"type":null},{"type":"Polygon","arcs":[[3]]}...
```

I'm aiming to create a map of the buildings in Stockholm and have the following D3 code:

```
<script>

var width = 960,
    height = 500;

var projection = d3.geo.albers()
    .translate(width/2, height/2)
    .scale(20000)
    .rotate([-18.0365, 0])
    .center([0, 59.3115]);

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

d3.json('buildings.json', function(err, city) {
    svg.append("path")
        .datum(topojson.object(city, city.objects.buildings.geometries))
        .attr("d", path);
}); 

</script>
```

However, this just loads a blank page and there are no errors in the javascript console. Not sure where to go next, any help will be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks,
Tom

Comment: The Albers projection is only really meant for North America. You're probably better off with a Mercator projection. Also check that the values you specify for translate, scale, rotate and center do what you think they should do.

Comment: Actually the Albers projection is fine for Sweden, and can be used anywhere on the globe. It may well be better for your purposes than Mercator because of the lower scale distortion. However, I would choose Universal Transverse Mercator myself, for very low distortion over any area up to the size of a typical European country (not including Russia).

Comment: Thankyou @Lars and @Graham for your comments, they both helped. I actually used mercator in the end and my original coordinates were off just a fraction, but it makes a big distance at the zoom levels I was using. Also, I discovered the `clipdst` flag for `ogr2ogr` - invaluable!